# Constructor not defined [Processing]

Tags: java, constructor, processing

I'm doing a really basic tutorial on ArrayList / Particle systems. I keep getting a "constructor is undefined error" and I can't figure out why. Googling brings up a lot of more complicated question/answers. What am I missing? Did this change in the last year?

```
ArrayList<Particle> plist;

void setup(){
    size(640, 360);
    plist = new ArrayList<Particle>();
    println(plist);
    plist.add(new Particle());
}

void draw(){
    background(255);


}


class Particle {
  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  float lifespan;

  Particle(PVector l){
    // For demonstration purposes we assign the Particle an initial velocity and constant acceleration.
    acceleration = new PVector(0,0.05);
    velocity = new PVector(random(-1,1),random(-2,0));
    location = l.get();
    lifespan = 255;
  }

  void run(){
    update();
    display();
  }

  void update(){
    velocity.add(acceleration);
    location.add(velocity);
    lifespan -= 2.0;
  }

  void display(){
    stroke(0, lifespan);
    fill(175, lifespan);
    ellipse(location.x, location.y,8,8);
  }

  boolean isDead(){
    if(lifespan < 0.0){
      return true;
    }else{
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your `Particle` constructor:

```
Particle(PVector l){
```

Notice that it takes a `PVector` argument.

This is how you're calling the `Particle` constructor:

```
plist.add(new Particle());
```

This line has an error: `the constructor`Particle()`does not exist.` And that's exactly what your problem is. The constructor `Particle()` doesn't exist. Only `Particle(PVector)` exists.

In other words, notice that you aren't giving it a `PVector` argument. That's what your error is telling you.

To fix this, you either need to supply a `PVector` argument, or you need to change the constructor so it no longer needs one.

Comment: Ahh ok. Constructors and classes are new to me, so I flubbed that. Error gone. I'll do some back reading on constructors.

Comment: @mishap_n When it comes to parameters, constructors are a lot like functions. You'd get a similar error if you tried to call the `ellipse()` function without any parameters.